# Sorting too slow

Tags: performance, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort, shellsort

So, I'm doing a project for my programming languages class, and i have to create a structure, sort it, and then show the time it takes to do it, the thing is bubble sorting(case 1) takes 60 sec to do it, insertion(case 2) 5 sec and selection (case 4) takes 10 sec. All this sorting 100000 elements. shell only takes 0.03 so i started thinking i might have something wrong with my algorithms. can some one help me?

```
void ordenesc(compleja * vd, int tam)
    {
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,aux=0,op=0,inc=0,minimo=0;
    char auxcad[20];
    clock_t start, end;
    double tiempo;

    op=menus(3);
    start = clock();
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1://Burbujeo
            for(i=1;i<=tam;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<tam-1;j++)
                {
                    if(vd[j].nro>vd[j+1].nro)
                    {
                        aux=vd[j].nro;
                        vd[j].nro=vd[j+1].nro;
                        vd[j+1].nro=aux;
                        strcpy(auxcad,vd[j].cad);
                        strcpy(vd[j].cad,vd[j+1].cad);
                        strcpy(vd[j+1].cad,auxcad);
                    }

                }
            }
            break;

        case 2://Inserccion
            for(i = 1; i < tam; i++)
            {
                aux=vd[i].nro;
                strcpy(auxcad,vd[i].cad);
                for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && vd[j].nro > aux; j--)
                {
                    vd[j+1].nro=vd[j].nro;
                    strcpy(vd[j+1].cad,vd[j].cad);
                    j--;
                }
                    vd[j+1].nro=aux;
                    strcpy(vd[j+1].cad,auxcad);
            }
            break;
                    case 3://Shell
                inc=(tam/2);
                while (inc > 0)
                {
                    for (i=0; i < tam; i++)
                    {
                      j = i;
                      aux = vd[i].nro;
                      strcpy(auxcad,vd[i].cad);
                      while ((j >= inc) && (vd[j-inc].nro > aux))
                      {
                        vd[j].nro = vd[j - inc].nro;
                        strcpy(vd[j].cad,vd[j-inc].cad);
                        j = j - inc;
                      }
                    vd[j].nro = aux;
                    strcpy(vd[j].cad,auxcad);
                    }
                    if (inc == 2)
                        inc = 1;
                    else
                        inc = inc * 5 / 11;
                  }
                break;
        case 4://Seleccion
            for(i=0;i<tam-1;i++)
            {
                minimo=i;
                for(j=i+1;j<tam;j++)
                {
                    if(vd[minimo].nro > vd[j].nro) minimo=j;
                }
                aux=vd[minimo].nro;
                vd[minimo].nro=vd[i].nro;
                vd[i].nro=aux;
                strcpy(auxcad,vd[minimo].cad);
                strcpy(vd[minimo].cad,vd[i].cad);
                strcpy(vd[i].cad,auxcad);
            }
            break;

        case 9:
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    end = clock();
    tiempo = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //system("cls");
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
    printf("%d   %s \n",vd[i].nro,vd[i].cad);}
    printf("\n Tardo %f segundos \n", tiempo);
    return;
}
```

P.d:Edited the text sorry for my english is not my first language and my brain is failing due to this.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your sort algorithm works as expected, you could add a check to the final loop that the elements are actually ordered when you print them. Its relatively unlikely that there is a fundamental error in the algorithm and it still sorts correctly.

One point of the exercise may be to show that sorting algorithms really matter, and selection sort is the only algorithm that has a better performance than O(n^2) in your list. So I wouldn't be too surprised by wide differences in performance.

One improvement you could make to bubble sort is that you only need to iterate over i elements in the inner loop (instead of tam), as the i-largest element will have bubbled up all the way in the inner loop.

Another improvement may be to just copy the pointers instead of the contents of the char arrays, e.g.

instead of

```
 char auxcad[20];

 ...

 strcpy(auxcad, vd[j].cad);
 strcpy(vd[j].cad, vd[j+1].cad);
 strcpy(vd[j+1].cad, auxcad);
```

you may want to write

```
 char* auxcad;

 ...

 auxcad = vd[j].cad;
 vd[j].cad = vd[j+1].cad;
 vd[j+1].cad = auxcad;
```

Comment: but the timings are bad shell is faster for a x100 percentage, i had a printf all of them were sorted properly

Comment: You sort 100000 elements. The "bad" algorithms have a complexity of O(n^2), so that makes 10000000000 operations. Shellsort gets closer to O(n log n) I think, which would be 500000. So it sounds all legit. I think the problem was really chosen to illustrate how big the difference can get.

Comment: is shell sorting that much better than the others? some friends told me that that bubble sort shouldn't take 30 sec to finish. I dont see the point of makeing me do this if shell is better on 1000 10000 and 100000 why would the other sortings exist? thats why i think i have something wrong in my code

Comment: Well as I wrote in my answer your implementation of bubble sort is missing an optimization. Also, you seem to be copying the string contents instead of just swapping the pointers, which may make your code slower than necessary.

Comment: Have added this to the answer (can't format in the comments)